# audio playback compatibility

Tags: video, audio

I have a lumia 640 (snapdragon 400) phone which refuses to play any MKV/AVC (h.264) files, with a very unhelpful error message. I'd like to know why the file can't be played - windows 8.1 update 2 has introduced support for the matroska container and I believe the snapdragon 400 processor supports most h.264 profiles. If it is somehow a codec issue, can it be fixed?

*Edit: seems to be related to the lack of AC3 support. Can this codec be added to the phone for use with any application?*

Comment: What is the unhelpful error message?

Comment: "unknown codec"

Comment: or "unable to play this file" depending on source and app.

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't play on inbuilt player, try it on third party players like [Moliplayer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/moliplayer-pro/9wzdncrfhwbv), Moli plays almost every format (45-50 formats to be exact). Give it a try, it might play.

Comment: Can't seem to find hard evidence that the MSM8226 Snapdragon 400 does support (hardware) AC3, but I would imagine so. That said, AC3 audio forces moliplayer into "software mode", which is very slow. Moliplayer crashes often, with AC3 files it crashes extremely often. I haven't tried CCPlayer, but I don't have enough room on my phone for local files. CCPlayer only plays files locally. Maybe I should try with an SD card sometime...

Comment: ...and that's why OS-level codec support would be great.